# Maven "class file for ... not found" compilation error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project. When I try to build it with Maven, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
  3.2:compile (default-compile) on project myProject: Compilation failure:
  Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ClassA.java:[32,38] cannot access ClassB
[ERROR] class file for ClassB not found
```

`ClassB` is inside another artifact, and that artifact is in the local repository. In fact, I have no problems building this project with the m2eclipse Maven plugin. It's only when I run `mvn compile` that the build fails.

What do I have to do to build from the command line?

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse might be bypassing your pom dependencies and 'helping' you by finding a dependency that is not in your pom.  Then when you run from command line eclipse isn't there to help anymore. I would double check your pom that you explicitly state dependency.  You can also try

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

for more info.

Comment: posting your pom.xml file and you src tree would help (linux tree command)

Comment: I had the same problem after some compile issues upstream during a full `mvn clean install`. The problem was Eclipse resolves from its own workspace but maven had to work with an incomplete or faulty local repository. Solution: perform a `mvn clean install` on the full project again (from the command line), which according to m2eclipse will yield no more compile errors upstream

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you have defined a usual class within the src/test/java instead of the src/main/java area which is sometimes the problem cause the eclipse things behaves a little bit different.

Answer (score -3):

add to pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <extdirs>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib</extdirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why do you think, this would help?